# Multiple Nested IF(AND(OR) Statements

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'd like to write a formula for multiple IF conditions that will show in my cell S23.

- IF: H23= "X" or "removed"
- THEN: S23= "X"

.

- IF: I23= "EWS" or "removed"
- THEN: S23= "EWS"

.

- IF: H23= "X" or "removed" **AND** I23="EWS" or "removed"
- THEN: S23= "X + EWS"

.

My formula:

`=if(H23="chex", "chex", IF(I23="EWS", "EWS", IF(H23="removed", "chex", (IF(I23="removed", "EWS", ""))))))))`

It works fine, but doesn't capture the last AND condition. I'm not using `=IF(OR(H23, ">0" etc` since this cell can also contain "NA". I only want it to capture the "X" or "removed" conditions.

Any idea how to add the last condition: IF both H23 and I23 contain "removed" or "X" / "EWS", respectively, then the result is "X+EWS"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked: `=IF(AND(OR(H23="x",H23="removed"),OR(I23="EWS",I23="removed")),"x+EWS",IF(OR(H23="x",H23="removed"),"x",IF(OR(I23="EWS",I23="removed"),"EWS","")))`

I modified @pnuts original formula: `=IF(AND(OR(H23="X",H23="removed"),OR(I23="EWS",I23="removed")),"X+EWS",IF(OR(H23="X",AND(H23="removed",I23<>"removed")),"X",IF(OR(I23="EWS",I23="removed"),"EWS","TBD")))`

Removed parts in bold: 
**AND(** H23="removed" **,I23<>"removed")**

Specifically, this argument:

from `IF(OR(H23="X",AND(H23="removed",I23<>"removed")),"X",`

to `IF(OR(H23="X",H23="removed"),"X",`

---

Was a team effort. Thank you @pnuts and @user0 for your help! :)